# ASP.NET SSL Set up Under IIS but site keeps bouncing back to http

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis-6

I have a certificate installed under IIS so I can use SSL for my sites

I have checked for a simple ASP.NET web site that this works.

For a more complex ASP.NET application I keep getting redirected to http whenever I hit https.

1. The IIS set up is identical for both
2. I use relative URLs throughout the application.

Is there anything ASP.NET or IIS specific that would cause a site to bounce from https to http?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any [HTTP modules](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307985) installed on your app?  Have you tried a [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) trace and if so what does it show?

Since the server seems to be accepting HTTPS traffic and you are not experiencing this with your simple app I presume there is a HTTP module in there.  These can intercept the traffic and if configured to can certainly exhibit the behavour you're experiencing.

Check your web.config file under the `<httpModules>` section, is anything there?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there was some "framework" code that picked up a setting "IsSslEnabled" that defaulted to false and redirect to http every time https was hit.

Grrrrr